# windows 11 impossible to verify error message

Tags: windows-11

How do I disable this seriously stupid message which requires account verification, when offline and presently impossible to verify?

[image]

Comment: Unlink the Microsoft Account or create a separate local account otherwise you’ll need to verify the account at least once.

Comment: • I can't unlink the microsoft account as that is not a viable solution.  • A separate local account is already present.  • The account has been verified at least 50 times already.  • This message only appears when there is no internet connection, and goes away after internet is present, so it's completely worthless.

Comment: Why can't you unlink the account?  Windows 11 most certainly supports local accounts without them being linked to a Microsoft Account.  Realistically there is no solution to your problem if the machine is not online, and in an isolated environment